# Get support TransitionInflater

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I am working with Tranistions between fragments. I want to inflate a Tranistion to be used using:

```
final Transition elementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(this)
   .inflateTransition(R.transition.sharedelement_enter);
```

This works fine after Lollipop but if I want to use the support lib

> com.android.support:transition

I do not know how to inflate the transition. There is no TransitionInflater in Support lib.

I checked the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/Transition.html but no clue.

Any idea how to create Transitions from XML with Support lib?

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@andkulikov/support-library-for-transitions-overview-and-comparison-c41be713cf8c

Comment: @Shailesh I have been already there. it does not solve my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea how to create Transitions from XML with Support lib?

TL;DR: **You don't.**

Slightly longer answer:

Inflating Transitions from XML is currently not implemented in the transitions support library.

You can extend `TransitionSet`, set it up the way you want to use it, and then instantiate it in lieu of the one you declared in XML.